# Custom autocomplete from example won't open in a dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use a custom autocomplete inside a dialog, but it the autocomplete wont open.

Open the codesandbox below.

You'll see:

1. A custom autocomplete ([from official doc's example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#customized-autocomplete) )
2. A button that opens a dialog, with another instance of the same custom autocomplete.

Click on "labels" of 1. And you see the autocomplete. Good.
Click on "Open" then try to open the autocomplete from the dialog. Impossible. Not Good.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-x-dialog-x-autofocus-758fn?file=/src/GitHubLabel.tsx

I believe the culprit is the input's autofocus (from 'renderInput').

For some reason, the autocomplete blurs as soon as it opens, and closes immediatly.
Removing the autofocus helps just a bit, you can then open the autocomplete, but it will disappear when clicking the input.

Related closed issue on github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20915

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that clicking on "Labels" is opening a `Popper` within a `Dialog`. By default, `Dialog` enforces keeping focus on itself. Opening the `Popper` is taking focus away from the `Dialog`. When `Dialog` brings focus back on itself, it is causing the `Popper` to close.

Adding the `disableEnforceFocus` prop on the `Dialog` fixes the problem. Here is a fixed version of your sandbox that includes some console logs that make it easier to see what is happening: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-x-dialog-x-autofocus-jk0ql?file=/src/InDialog.jsx.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

The dialog is loosing the focus because 'Popper' uses a 'Portal' right?




As an alternative solution I could use `disablePortal` on `Popper`.

I do prefer yours.

I found this related issue. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15694

Comment: Using `disablePortal` on `Popper` won't work well without more significant changes since it then gets constrained by the dialog size.